# Dataflow Program on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /*
 code for getting the data from the REST api and putting it into
HashMap Collection and then creating the pipeline from that collection and writing the pipeline into bq table  */

String[] credentials = {"--project=" + projectId, "--stagingLocation=" + staggingLocation};
 PipelineOptionsFactory.Builder builder = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(credentials);
        PipelineOptions options = builder.create();

```
    //Setting to run the pipeline in google cloud.By Changing this parameter we can run even in local mode
    options.setRunner(DataflowPipelineRunner.class);

    //Creating pipeline with above options
    Pipeline youTubeChannelPipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
     PCollection<String> lines = null;
     lines = youTubeChannelPipeline.apply(Create.of(allValues)).setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of());

   //Transforming PCollection<String> to PCollection<TableRow> and then writing to bq
```

bqRows = lines.apply(ParDo.named("Transforming String To TableRow").of(new DoFn() {
                @Override
                public void processElement(ProcessContext pc) throws Exception {
                    TableRow tmpRow = new TableRow();
                    String[] columns = pc.element().split(YoutubeConstants.COMA_DELIMITER);
                    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_col; i++) {
                        tmpRow.set(YoutubeConstants.CHANNEL_LEVEL_HEADERS[i], columns[i]);
                    }
                    pc.output(tmpRow);
                }
            }));

```
        //Writing the rows in bq table
        bqRows.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                .named("Write To BQ")
                .to(destination_path)
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));


    youTubeChannelPipeline.run();


W 12:36:16.124 /demo
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner#fromOptions
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:228)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:161)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:117)
    at myapp.DemoServlet.doGet(DemoServlet.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:482)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-8f9b045d763b7321(Request.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:161)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:117)
    at myapp.DemoServlet.doGet(DemoServlet.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get application default credentials. Please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for details on how to specify credentials. This version of the SDK is dependent on the gcloud core component version 2015.02.05 or newer to be able to get credentials from the currently authorized user via gcloud auth.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.Credentials.getCredential(Credentials.java:122)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcpCredentialFactory.getCredential(GcpCredentialFactory.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.GcpOptions$GcpUserCredentialsFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.GcpOptions$GcpUserCredentialsFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:175)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getGcpCredential(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.Transport.newDataflowClient(Transport.java:120)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowPipelineDebugOptions$DataflowClientFactory.create(DataflowPipelineDebugOptions.java:157)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowPipelineDebugOptions$DataflowClientFactory.create(DataflowPipelineDebugOptions.java:154)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getDataflowClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.<init>(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:160)
  <continued in next message>
W 12:36:16.124 <continued from previous message>
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.fromOptions(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:155)
    ... 34 more
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Application Default Credentials failed to create the Google App Engine service account credentials class com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper. Check that the component 'google-api-client-appengine' is deployed.
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.tryGetAppEngineCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:274)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredentialUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:159)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:86)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.Credentials.getCredential(Credentials.java:120)
    ... 48 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-8f9b045d763b7321(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:136)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.forName(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:208)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.tryGetAppEngineCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:259)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Support for getting credentials compatible with Dataflow via [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) in AppEngine exists in version 1.9.20+ of the Google API libraries. Please make sure that your WAR that you deploy to AppEngine contains google-api-client version 1.9.20+ and google-api-client-appengine version 1.9.20+. Beware that you may need to upgrade other dependencies because of this change.